# Scheme, passing lambda as a function argument - Need help understanding args

Tags: scheme, arguments

This is a homework assignment:

> return a list containing all elements of a given list that satisfy a given predicate. For example,
>
> ```
> (filter (lambda (x) (< x 5)) '(3 9 5 8 2 4 7))
> ```
>
> Should return (3 2 4).

I just started scheme yesterday so I'm a complete noob. If I am understanding the syntax of this function function call correctly, "filter" is the function and "(lambda (x) (< x 5)" is the argument. Is this similar to an anonymous function in java?

EDIT:

I found some code from another post on stackoverflow. They just straight out answered the question: Here is what they wrote:

```
   (define (my-filter pred lst)
     (cond ((null? lst) null)
       ((pred (first lst))
          (cons (first lst) (my-filter pred (rest lst))))
       (else (my-filter pred (rest lst)))))
```

Which is good, and it works, but before I use any of it I want to understand it. "pred" is a function, yet in this instance they are passing (< x 5) to it and it is somehow accepting this value. That I do not understand.

Can someone explain to me what happens during this program? I don't understand the logic behind what is happening.

Comment: Just a pedantic note. Java does not have anonymous functions. It has anonymous classes which are often used to simulate "lambdas".

Comment: Historical note: in 2012, Java did not have anonymous functions (a.k.a. "closures")... but as of Java 8 (iirc), it now does.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are spot-on. In addition, if it's helpful to you, this program means the same thing:

```
#lang racket

(define (less-than-five x) (< x 5))

(filter less-than-five '(3 9 5 8 2 4 7))
```

The key difference between Scheme/Racket and Java here is that

```
less-than-five
```

is a value; in Java, methods are not values.

EDIT: I see that you added a bunch to your question. I'm impressed that you 
have followup questions, rather than just taking what you got :)

I think that the best way to answer this is to focus on what happens when you 
make a function call, and to use ... the stepper!

Oh, what the heck.  I made a video, and slapped it up on YouTube:

http://youtu.be/2hmamosiqGI

Comment: Sorry, since I am a noob here I can't get the formatting right so i will just post in answer.

Comment: I love it, stackoverflow meets Khan Academy

Comment: Thanks for the video, it was super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're calling the `filter` function and one of its arguments is `(lambda (x) (< x 5))`. (And there's another argument, your list of numbers.) And yes, it's very much like an anonymous class with a single method in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `lambda` defines a function in scheme. If the function is not assigned to a variable by name then it is basically the same as an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of the problem in Java using Google's Guava library:

```
Iterables.filter(asList(3,9,5,8,2,4,7), new Predicate<Integer>() {

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Integer a) {
        return a < 5;
    }

});
```

I bring it up to show that Java does not have anonymous functions but rather anonymous classes. Java does not have functions as a first class data type. I bring this up because if your taking a course (which I presume you are) this may very well be asked on a test.